# In Python, can I start a background worker at the beginning, do some computation, and wait for its results at the end of the same function?

Tags: python, backgroundworker

In Python, how can I start a process/worker at the beginning of a function and wait for it at the end? Something like:

```
def my_function():
    worker_ref = start_long_computation()
    local_result = do_heavy_computations()
    return worker_ref.wait_for_result() or local_result
```

This way, `wait_for_result()` would likely return immediately if the results were already processed between `start_long_computation()` and `do_heavy_computations()`.

Comment: You should look into __threading__ and you wait for a task to finish by [__joining__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) it.

Comment: An alternative to threading is multiprocessing. Same concepts as threads but in different processes.